# Use of 'Few and far between'

Tags: grammar

Most often, I see this phrase following 'are', as in:

> Opportunities are few and far between.

However, is the construction below also grammatical?

> Such work is few and far between.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly this is not grammatical.

The "far between" means there is a long distance or a long time between the things being talked about. This requires there to be at least two things. But "work" in your example is uncountable, and uncountable things are treated as singular.

I would suggest converting the sentence to something like:

> Such jobs are few and far between

> Such work opportunities are few and far between.